# Copy and paste typekits @font-face rule

Tags: css, fonts, base64, font-face, typekit

If you are using typekit, it loads a CSS file, where you can find something like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "futura-pt";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url("data:font/opentype;base64,d09GRgABA [...] AAAA");
```

Is there any reason, why I shouldn't open my site in different browsers, copy the base64 codes for the other file formats and have the fonts on my server instead of loading them with js? Is that even legal? Will it work everywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "The Typekit web font license requires that the fonts be added to a website with the JavaScript embed code that we provide."

Source: http://help.typekit.com/customer/portal/articles/1341590#web-host